# ActiveRecord instance settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm curious if there's a gem or way of doing per-model settings. For example, user preferences.

I'd like to have defaults per model (say a class attribute), but definable (on another table! I don't want a serializable field on my model).

For example:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.settings.newsletter # => true
```

There would be a model for UserSetting that has a schema of key => string, value => string, type => string (Boolean, Date, String, etc...)

**UPDATE:**

Here is my solution to this in the end. Supports value types for settings (Boolean, Time, etc)

```
    def setting(key, whiny=true)
      s = user_settings.where(:key => key).first

      if s
        case s.value_type
        when 'Boolean'
          s.value.to_i == 1
        when 'Time'
          Time.parse(s.value)
        else
          s.value
        end
      else
        if whiny
          raise NameError, "Setting key #{key} does not exist for #{name}."
        else
          nil
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement this with User has_many UserSettings, and UserSetting is user_id, key, and value.
Maybe have a convenience method for accessing them, like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_settings
  def setting(key)
    user_settings.where(:key => key).first.try(&:value)
  end
end

class UserSetting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Then, you can go

```
user = User.find(1)
user.setting('newsletter') # => true/false (or nil if that setting doesn't exist)
```

Comment: Looks great, just needs to be .try(:value)

Comment: @RobertRoss Whoops, yeah. Fixed that. Thanks.

Comment: Updated original post if you're interested in the final outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The `has_settings` gem appears to do this, but alas doesn't appear to be maintained. [This fork](https://github.com/layby42/has_settings) has Rails 3 support, at least.

If you can't find a gem that suits your needs it's pretty straightforward to implement on your own with a simple has_many relation and a little association extension magic, e.g. (untested):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :settings do
    # association extension
    def method_missing name, *args
      key = name.to_s

      # setter
      if key.ends_with? '='
        key.chop!
        new_val = args.first

        setting = find_or_create_by_key key

        setting.update_attribute(:value, new_val) &&
          @settings[key] = new_val                && # KISS cache
          true  # to mirror the semantics of update_attribute

      # getter
      elsif @settings.has_key? name # is it cached?
        @settings[name]

      elsif setting = where(:key => name).select(:value).first
        @settings[name] = setting.value # KISS cache again

      else
        super
      end

    end
  end

end

class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  serialize :value # so we don't have to bother with an extra :type attribute
end

class CreateSettings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :settings do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.string :key
      t.string :value
    end
  end

  def down
    remove_table :settings
  end
end
```

Obviously this gets the job done but obviously isn't very robust so you may encounter gotchas.